# how to stretch the video feed from camera on p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm using p5.js and created a program not using canvas(). Here's my code:

```
function setup() {
  asciiDiv = createDiv();
  noCanvas();
  video = createCapture(VIDEO);
  video.size(64, 48);
}
```

how do I increase/stretch the size of the video to full screen without hurting the aspect ratio?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Is there anything stopping you from simply putting bigger numbers into your `video.size()` call, like `video.size(640, 480)`?